# EPiServer: populate selectionfactory drop down list with content from array?

Tags: c#, episerver

I have a variable called cultures which contains a long list of all culture codes such as:

- en-US
- en-GB
- en-AU
- de-DE
- etc

I would like to create a drop-down list with text and values populated with these codes.

This is what I have come up so far but that it is not working i.e. my drop-down `HrefLangName` contains no entries.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using EPiServer.Core;
using EPiServer.DataAbstraction;
using EPiServer.DataAnnotations;
using EPiServer.Shell.ObjectEditing;

namespace Site.Models.Blocks
{
    [ContentType(GUID = "1ffec6b3-06a3-4fbd-b541-7d02e8302811")]
    public class HrefLangBlock : BlockData
    {

        [Display(Order = 1)]
        [SelectOne(SelectionFactoryType = typeof(HrefLangSelectionFactory))]
        public virtual string HrefLangName { get; set; }

        [Display(Order = 1)]
        public virtual string HrefLangLink { get; set; }

    }

    public class HrefLangSelectionFactory : ISelectionFactory
    {
        public IEnumerable<ISelectItem> GetSelections(ExtendedMetadata metadata)
        {

            CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

            var list = new List<ISelectItem>();

            foreach (var culturecode in cultures)
            {
                new SelectItem()
                {
                    Text = culturecode.ToString(),
                    Value = culturecode
                };
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use Linq?

```
public IEnumerable<ISelectItem> GetSelections(ExtendedMetadata metadata)
{
    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
    return cultures.Select(x => new SelectItem() { Text = culturecode.ToString(), Value = culturecode });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by re-writing my foreach loop to contain the following instead:

```
foreach (var culturecode in cultures)
            {

                list.Add(new SelectItem()
                {
                    Text = culturecode.ToString(),
                    Value = culturecode
                });
            }
```